# Short story and/or excerpt of book about alien culture with orange eyes and human colony on alien planet?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

A story I read as a short story/book excerpt in an English textbook in middle school in 2007 and haven't found since. There is an alien girl with orange eyes and a colony of humans has moved onto the planet. I remember it being dusty and barren. Anyone remember this?

Comment: This immediately made me think of [The Keeper of the Isis Light](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1190250.The_Keeper_of_the_Isis_Light) by Monica Hughes.  But since Olwen doesn't have orange eyes and isn't technically alien, I am not posting this as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

This might be Ray Bradbury's "The Naming of Names" also known as "Dark They were, with Golden Eyes." Humans move to Mars and find themselves changing, I believe. I also read it in a textbook, albeit in middle school.

Here's a quote from the story that mentions the eyes:

> The sun was hot, the day quiet. There was only an immense staring burn upon the land. They moved along the canal, the father, the mother, the racing children in their swimsuits. They stopped and ate meat sandwiches. He saw their skin baking brown. And he saw the yellow eyes of his wife and his children, their eyes that were never yellow before. A few tremblings shook him, but were carried off in waves of pleasant heat as he lay in the sun. He was too tired to be afraid.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Dusty certainly might describe Mars; if you can find a quote about a Martian girl with orange eyes, this would be a very good answer.

Comment: Here's a quote found online - "The sun was hot, the day quiet. There was only an immense staring burn upon the land. They moved along the canal, the father, the mother, the racing children in their swimsuits. They stopped and ate meat sandwiches. He saw their skin baking brown. And he saw the yellow eyes of his wife and his children, their eyes that were never yellow before. A few tremblings shook him, but were carried off in waves of pleasant heat as he lay in the sun. He was too tired to be afraid."